# How to use GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY in OpenGL 3.2

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures

So I've tried following the [docs](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture), however I can't seem to get a texture 2D array to work.

```
-(GLint)buildTextureArray:(NSArray *)arrayOfImages
{
    GLImage *sample = [GLImage imageWithImageName:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:0] shouldFlip:NO]; //Creates a sample to examine texture width and height
    int width = sample.width, height = sample.height;
    GLsizei count = (GLsizei)arrayOfImages.count; 

    GLuint texture3D;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture3D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, texture3D);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, width);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT);
    glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, count, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV, NULL);

    int i = 0;
    for (NSString *name in arrayOfImages) //Loops through everything in arrayOfImages
    {
        GLImage *image = [GLImage imageWithImageName:name shouldFlip:NO]; //My own class that loads an image
        glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, i, image.width, image.height, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.data);
        i++;
    }
    return texture3D;
}

//Setting Uniform elsewhere
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, textureArray);
glUniform1i(textures, 0);    


//Fragment Shader
#version 150

in vec3 texCoords;

uniform sampler2DArray textures;

out vec3 color;

void main()
{
    color = texture(textures, texCoords.stp, 0).rgb;
}
```

I am able to load individual textures with the same texture parameters, but I can't get it to work with the texture 2D array.  All I get is a black texture.  Why is this happening?

Comment: Could be a mipmaps problem.. Do you see the texture if you zoom so that 1 texel approximately takes 1 pixel ? Also, your p tex coord should be between 0 and arrayOfImages.size-1, is that valid ?

Comment: @Calvin1602 No, my entire screen is completely black, and yes, my p tex coord are all set to 0 for current testing purposes.

Comment: If you're going to use `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` make sure you upload some mipmaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
```

Your texture in fact does *not* have mipmaps. So stop telling OpenGL that it does.

Also, ***always*** set the [mipmap range parameters (`GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LAYER` and `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LAYER`)](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Mipmap_range) for your texture. Or better yet, use [texture storage to allocate your texture's storage](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Immutable_texture_storage), and it will do it for you.

Comment: I've changed it and I'm still getting a black screen.  Is it possibly because glPixelStore doesn't support GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY?

Comment: And also as stated in my question, I'm working on OpenGL 3.2, so texture storage are not supported.

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer Huh? `glPixelStore` doesn't know anything about any `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` so there isn't even a notion of *"support"*. Of course you have to set it up properly for uploading pixel data to the GPU, which you already did (though an alignment of 4 would have worked, too, since you use RGBA data). Wait, your image data does contain 4 unsigned bytes for each pixel, right?

Comment: @ChristianRau My image data should have 4 unsigned bytes for each pixels.  As stated in my question, I am able to use the textures individually using GL_TEXTURE_2D using the same texture parameter's and pixel store.

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer: "*I'm working on OpenGL 3.2, so texture storage are not supported.*" Nonsense. ARB_texture_storage is a ([core](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Extensions#Core_Extensions)) extension. Unless you're working on MacOSX or some Intel card, there's every chance you have access to it.

Comment: @NicolBolas If you didn't notice, my code is in Objective-C, which is a huge indication of OpenGL on Mac OSX.  I'll indicate that next time I post another question.

Answer (score 0):

for 2d_array textures 'v' component of texcoords varies from 0-height and 'w' from 0-depth(as it denote layer). Try changing these texcordinates.