# How to use GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY for binding multiple textures (as array)?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, textures

According to this answer: [OpenGL sampler2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72648980/opengl-sampler2d-array)

> You cannot use a fragment shader input variable to index an array of texture samplers. You have to use a sampler2DArray (`GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY`) instead of an array of sampler2D (`GL_TEXTURE_2D`)

So I tried to do exactly that - generate `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION

#include <stb/stb_image.h>

#include <test/main/shader.hpp>

uint32_t LoadTexture(const std::string& filepath) {
    int w, h, bits;

    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
    uint8_t *pixels = stbi_load(filepath.c_str(), &w, &h, &bits, 4);

    uint32_t texture_id;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, texture_id);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

//    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
//    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    stbi_image_free(pixels);
    return texture_id;
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60513272/alternative-for-glbindtextureunit-for-opengl-versions-less-than-4-5
void Bind2DArrayTexture(int unit, uint32_t texture) {
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + unit);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, texture);
}


int main() {
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(960, 540, "test", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (window == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "failed to create GLFW window\n";
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, [](GLFWwindow *_, int width, int height) {
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    });
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        std::cerr << "failed to initialize GLAD\n";
    }
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    Shader shader("assets/GLSL/test.glsl");
    shader.Bind();
    int samplers[2] = {0, 1};
    shader.SetIntArray("u_textures", samplers, 2);

    uint32_t quad_va, quad_vb, quad_ib;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &quad_va);
    glBindVertexArray(quad_va);

    float vertices[] = {
            // first texture - logo.png
            -1.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            -1.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

            // second texture - chessboard.png
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
    };

    glGenBuffers(1, &quad_vb);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vb);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6, nullptr);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6,
                          reinterpret_cast<const void *>(sizeof(float) * 3));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6,
                          reinterpret_cast<const void *>(sizeof(float) * 5));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    uint32_t indices[] = {
            0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0,
            4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4
    };
    glGenBuffers(1, &quad_ib);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_ib);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    uint32_t logo_id = LoadTexture("assets/textures/logo.png");
    uint32_t chessboard_id = LoadTexture("assets/textures/chessboard.png");

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        shader.Bind();
        Bind2DArrayTexture(0, logo_id);
        Bind2DArrayTexture(1, chessboard_id);

        glBindVertexArray(quad_va);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 12, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}
```

and shader:

```
#type vertex
#version 450 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 a_pos;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 a_texcoord;
layout(location = 0) in float a_texindex;

out vec2 v_texcoord;
out float v_texindex;

void main()
{
        v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
        v_texindex = a_texindex;
        gl_Position = vec4(a_pos, 1.0);
}

#type fragment
#version 450 core

in vec2 v_texcoord;
in float v_texindex;

uniform sampler2DArray u_textures;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
        color = texture(u_textures, vec3(v_texcoord.xy, v_texindex));
}
```

Where the Shader class, which is not shown simply parses the shader file with both, vertex and fragment part. Now both textures are distinguished via last attrib pointer, one float 0.0f for first texture, 1.0f for second one. But in the output, I only see 2 black squares (which should have the textures in it), so how to use the `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` to load both textures (and thus calling 2 times `Bind2DArrayTexture`, since that is the target, I have no way how to make an actual array of both textures).

Now please do not mark this as duplicate to the referenced answer (provided at the beginning of this question). Because there is only shown the usage of the shader (which I did), but no actual usage of C++ side (using the `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` for 2 distinct textures). So it won't answer my question and thus my question cannot be duplicate

PS: for completness, here is the shader class:

*header*:

```
#ifndef TEST_SHADER_HPP
#define TEST_SHADER_HPP

#include <string>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>

class Shader {
public:
    explicit Shader(const std::string& filepath);

    void Bind() const;

    void SetInt(const std::string& name, int value) const;

    void SetIntArray(const std::string& name, int *values, int count);

    void SetFloat(const std::string& name, float value) const;

    void SetVec3(const std::string& name, const glm::vec3& vec) const;

    void SetVec4(const std::string& name, const glm::vec4& vec) const;

    void SetMat4(const std::string& name, const glm::mat4& mat) const;

private:
    static void CheckCompileErrors(uint32_t shader_id, const std::string& type, const std::string& filepath);

    uint32_t id_;
};

#endif //TEST_SHADER_HP
```

*source*:

```
#include <test/main/shader.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include <glad/glad.h>

void Shader::CheckCompileErrors(uint32_t shader_id, const std::string& type, const std::string& filepath) {
    int success;
    char infoLog[1024];
    if (type != "PROGRAM") {
        glGetShaderiv(shader_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success) {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader_id, 1024, nullptr, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::COMPILATION_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "filepath: "
                      << filepath;
        }
    } else {
        glGetProgramiv(shader_id, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success) {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shader_id, 1024, nullptr, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::PROGRAM_LINKING_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "filepath: "
                      << filepath;
        }
    }
}

Shader::Shader(const std::string& filepath) {
    // 1. divide vertex and fragment part
    enum class ShaderType {
        NONE = -1, VERTEX = 0, FRAGMENT = 1
    };
    std::ifstream stream(filepath);
    std::string line;
    std::stringstream ss[2];
    ShaderType type = ShaderType::NONE;
    while (getline(stream, line)) {
        if (line.find("#type") != std::string::npos) {
            if (line.find("vertex") != std::string::npos) {
                type = ShaderType::VERTEX;
            } else if (line.find("fragment") != std::string::npos) {
                type = ShaderType::FRAGMENT;
            } else {
                std::cout << "Unknown shader: " << line << '\n';
            }
        } else {
            if (type == ShaderType::NONE) {
                std::cout << "No shader defined" << '\n';
            } else {
                ss[(int) type] << line << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
    std::string vertex_code = ss[(int) ShaderType::VERTEX].str();
    std::string fragment_code = ss[(int) ShaderType::FRAGMENT].str();

    // 2. convert, compile and link sources to shader program
    // 2.1 convert string to c str
    const char *vertex_str = vertex_code.c_str();
    const char *fragment_str = fragment_code.c_str();
    // 2.2.1 vertex shader
    uint32_t vertex_id = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex_id, 1, &vertex_str, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(vertex_id);
    CheckCompileErrors(vertex_id, "VERTEX", filepath);
    // 2.2.2 fragment shader
    uint32_t fragment_id = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment_id, 1, &fragment_str, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(fragment_id);
    CheckCompileErrors(fragment_id, "FRAGMENT", filepath);
    // 2.3 shader program
    id_ = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(id_, vertex_id);
    glAttachShader(id_, fragment_id);
    glLinkProgram(id_);
    CheckCompileErrors(id_, "PROGRAM", filepath);
    // 2.4 delete the shaders as they're linked into program and no longer necessary
    glDeleteShader(vertex_id);
    glDeleteShader(fragment_id);
}

void Shader::Bind() const {
    glUseProgram(id_);
}

void Shader::SetInt(const std::string& name, int value) const {
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(id_, name.c_str()), value);
}

void Shader::SetIntArray(const std::string& name, int *values, int count) {
    glUniform1iv(glGetUniformLocation(id_, name.c_str()), count, values);
}

void Shader::SetFloat(const std::string& name, float value) const {
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(id_, name.c_str()), value);
}

void Shader::SetVec4(const std::string& name, const glm::vec4& vec) const {
    glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(id_, name.c_str()), vec.x, vec.y, vec.z, vec.w);
}

void Shader::SetVec3(const std::string& name, const glm::vec3& vec) const {
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(id_, name.c_str()), vec.x, vec.y, vec.z);
}

void Shader::SetMat4(const std::string& name, const glm::mat4& mat) const {
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(id_, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
}
```

Comment: For a `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` target texture you have to use [`glTexImage3D`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage3D.xhtml) instead of `glTexImage2D`

Comment: @Rabbid76, why? Those are simple png images, nothing 3D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`glTexImage2D`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) with target `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` generates a `INVALID_ENUM` error. Actually a `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` are multiple `GL_TEXTURE_2D` textures. You have to specify the size of the 2D texture and the number of textures in the array. Therefore the texture needs to be specified with [`glTexImage3D`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage3D.xhtml). e.g.: for array size 1:

<s>`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);`</s>

```cpp
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 1, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

You also need to set `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` because the initial value of `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`. If you don't change it and don't create mipmaps, the texture will not be "complete" and will not be "shown".

```cpp
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

---

For more than one 2D texture, I suggest creating the 3D texture image for the desired number of 2D textures (`noOfTextures`)

```cpp
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, noOfTextures, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
```

and specify the individual 2D textures with [`glTexSubImage3D`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexSubImage3D.xhtml). You have to call `glTexSubImage3D` for each individual 2D image, the *zoffset* (`textureIndex`) is the index of the texture in the array and has to be different for each 2D texture.

```cpp
glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, textureIndex, w, h, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels)
```

Of course, the individual 2D images must be of the same size.

Comment: Ok, I read some wikis and docs. There is similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372058/how-to-use-gl-texture-2d-array-in-opengl-3-2). Now my question is - the `glTexImage3D` takes width and height. But I have 2 images. Should I use the width and height of the first image or the second one?

Comment: @milanHrabos As I mentioned in my answer: *"Of course, the individual 2D images must be of the same size."*

Comment: Well, so this solution works only for this specific scenario where the images have the same size... So if they dont have the same size. I guess I should make another question? :)

Comment: @milanHrabos Yes. But you asked about `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY`. The title of your question is *"How to use GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY for binding multiple textures (as array)?"*

Comment: @milanHrabos You want your renderer to perform well. You can support it by making sure that all textures have the same resolution and you can use `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY`. You know the textures so you can scale them too.

Comment: Fair enough. Well that's the answer of question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72648980/opengl-sampler2d-array) my previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372058/how-to-use-gl-texture-2d-array-in-opengl-3-2) was marked as duplicate. So my previous question was not duplicate after all...

Comment: Thanks for the `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` but as I see now, this is not suitable for my case (having 2 different sized images). So I would like you to look to my previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75973159/binding-2-different-texture-units-but-only-one-will-get-rendered-in-opengl) which was marked as duplicate, but apparently is not

Comment: @milanHrabos In your previous question you tried to use an array of `GL_TEXTURE_2D` and index the array with an none dynamically uniform index (`texture(u_textures[index], v_texcoord);`). This is not possible and answered in the duplicate question.

Comment: Yes, there is mentioned that fact. But in the linked answers, there is - again - no C++ side solution. And we are back where we were. I am aware of that fact I cannot use float as index, but that is shader side. Now I did read documentation, but opengl api is cumbersome so I cannot find a C++ solution myself and none is provided in the linked answers. Peculiar situation

Comment: @milanHrabos There are just 3 solutions: 1.  use multiple draw calls. 2. use `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` and scale the textures to equal size 3. use a texture atlas (1 big texture with tiles of the same size)

Comment: The whole point was I wanted to learn "batching" , which is the opposite of multiple draw calls. So this option goes out. 2. use `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY`,  well I don't know how to scale texture to the same size and this solution seems not to be universal, since you almost never have images of the same size. So I guess the only possibility is to learn what atlas are how to use them

Comment: @milanHrabos No. For an atlas the textures have to have the same size, too. For a batch renderer, the textures should have the same resolution anyway. Scale the textures with an App (Gimp, Paint, etc.)

Comment: Ok, I have downloaded images of the same size 1024x1024 and recreate `BuildTextureArray` from (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372058/how-to-use-gl-texture-2d-array-in-opengl-3-2). Now I got segfault: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75979866/how-to-build-texture-array-in-opengl