# How to build an array texture in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, textures

Having this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION

#include <stb/stb_image.h>

#include <test/main/shader.hpp>

// size of the images has to be the same
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75976623/how-to-use-gl-texture-2d-array-for-binding-multiple-textures-as-array/75976728?noredirect=1#comment134006728_75976728
uint32_t BuildTextureArray(const std::vector<std::string>& paths) {
    int width, height;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
    uint8_t *data_of_first = stbi_load(paths[0].c_str(), &width, &height, nullptr, 4);

    uint32_t array_id;
    glGenTextures(1, &array_id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, array_id);
    glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, paths.size(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data_of_first);
    for (int i = 1; i < paths.size(); i++) {
        uint8_t *data = stbi_load(paths[i].c_str(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, 4);
        glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, i, width, height, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    }

    return array_id;
}

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(960, 540, "test", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (window == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "failed to create GLFW window\n";
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, [](GLFWwindow *_, int width, int height) {
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    });
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        std::cerr << "failed to initialize GLAD\n";
    }
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    Shader shader("assets/GLSL/test.glsl");
    shader.Bind();
    uint32_t texture_array = BuildTextureArray({"assets/textures/logo.png", "assets/textures/homer.png"});
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, texture_array);
    shader.SetInt("u_textures", 0);

    uint32_t quad_va, quad_vb, quad_ib;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &quad_va);
    glBindVertexArray(quad_va);

    float vertices[] = {
            // first texture - logo.png
            -1.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            -1.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

            // second texture - homer.png
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
    };

    glGenBuffers(1, &quad_vb);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vb);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6, nullptr);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6,
                          reinterpret_cast<const void *>(sizeof(float) * 3));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6,
                          reinterpret_cast<const void *>(sizeof(float) * 5));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    uint32_t indices[] = {
            0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0,
            4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4
    };
    glGenBuffers(1, &quad_ib);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_ib);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        shader.Bind();

        glBindVertexArray(quad_va);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 12, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}
```

and shader:

```
#type vertex
#version 450 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 a_pos;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 a_texcoord;
layout(location = 0) in float a_texindex;

out vec2 v_texcoord;
out float v_texindex;

void main()
{
        v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
        v_texindex = a_texindex;
        gl_Position = vec4(a_pos, 1.0);
}

#type fragment
#version 450 core

in vec2 v_texcoord;
in float v_texindex;

uniform sampler2DArray u_textures;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
        color = texture(u_textures, vec3(v_texcoord.xy, v_texindex));
}
```

Where the Shader class, which is not shown simply parses the shader file with both, vertex and fragment part. Now both textures are distinguished via last attrib pointer, one float 0.0f for first texture, 1.0f for second one. Running this will result in segfault. The segfault is caused by `BuildTextureArray()` function (it would run without it, but there would be no array texture of course). I have tried to create that function according to [How to use GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY in OpenGL 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372058/how-to-use-gl-texture-2d-array-in-opengl-3-2), so should not be duplicate of that since I am using the code there. And since I don't have debugger at hand, I cannot walk through that function. But since it was just copied, what went wrong? Images `logo.png` and `homer.png` are the same size 1024x1024

PS: for completness, here is the shader class:

*header*:

```
#ifndef TEST_SHADER_HPP
#define TEST_SHADER_HPP

#include <string>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>

class Shader {
public:
    explicit Shader(const std::string& filepath);

    void Bind() const;

    void SetInt(const std::string& name, int value) const;

    void SetIntArray(const std::string& name, int *values, int count);

    void SetFloat(const std::string& name, float value) const;

    void SetVec3(const std::string& name, const glm::vec3& vec) const;

    void SetVec4(const std::string& name, const glm::vec4& vec) const;

    void SetMat4(const std::string& name, const glm::mat4& mat) const;

private:
    static void CheckCompileErrors(uint32_t shader_id, const std::string& type, const std::string& filepath);

    uint32_t id_;
};

#endif //TEST_SHADER_HP
```

*source*:

```
#include <test/main/shader.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include <glad/glad.h>

void Shader::CheckCompileErrors(uint32_t shader_id, const std::string& type, const std::string& filepath) {
    int success;
    char infoLog[1024];
    if (type != "PROGRAM") {
        glGetShaderiv(shader_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success) {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader_id, 1024, nullptr, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::COMPILATION_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "filepath: "
                      << filepath;
        }
    } else {
        glGetProgramiv(shader_id, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success) {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shader_id, 1024, nullptr, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::PROGRAM_LINKING_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "filepath: "
                      << filepath;
        }
    }
}

Shader::Shader(const std::string& filepath) {
    // 1. divide vertex and fragment part
    enum class ShaderType {
        NONE = -1, VERTEX = 0, FRAGMENT = 1
    };
    std::ifstream stream(filepath);
    std::string line;
    std::stringstream ss[2];
    ShaderType type = ShaderType::NONE;
    while (getline(stream, line)) {
        if (line.find("#type") != std::string::npos) {
            if (line.find("vertex") != std::string::npos) {
                type = ShaderType::VERTEX;
            } else if (line.find("fragment") != std::string::npos) {
                type = ShaderType::FRAGMENT;
            } else {
                std::cout << "Unknown shader: " << line << '\n';
            }
        } else {
            if (type == ShaderType::NONE) {
                std::cout << "No shader defined" << '\n';
            } else {
                ss[(int) type] << line << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
    std::string vertex_code = ss[(int) ShaderType::VERTEX].str();
    std::string fragment_code = ss[(int) ShaderType::FRAGMENT].str();

    // 2. convert, compile and link sources to shader program
    // 2.1 convert string to c str
    const char *vertex_str = vertex_code.c_str();
    const char *fragment_str = fragment_code.c_str();
    // 2.2.1 vertex shader
    uint32_t vertex_id = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex_id, 1, &vertex_str, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(vertex_id);
    CheckCompileErrors(vertex_id, "VERTEX", filepath);
    // 2.2.2 fragment shader
    uint32_t fragment_id = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment_id, 1, &fragment_str, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(fragment_id);
    CheckCompileErrors(fragment_id, "FRAGMENT", filepath);
    // 2.3 shader program
    id_ = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(id_, vertex_id);
    glAttachShader(id_, fragment_id);
    glLinkProgram(id_);
    CheckCompileErrors(id_, "PROGRAM", filepath);
    // 2.4 delete the shaders as they're linked into program and no longer necessary
    glDeleteShader(vertex_id);
    glDeleteShader(fragment_id);
}

void Shader::Bind() const {
    glUseProgram(id_);
}

void Shader::SetInt(const std::string& name, int value) const {
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(id_, name.c_str()), value);
}

void Shader::SetIntArray(const std::string& name, int *values, int count) {
    glUniform1iv(glGetUniformLocation(id_, name.c_str()), count, values);
}

void Shader::SetFloat(const std::string& name, float value) const {
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(id_, name.c_str()), value);
}

void Shader::SetVec4(const std::string& name, const glm::vec4& vec) const {
    glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(id_, name.c_str()), vec.x, vec.y, vec.z, vec.w);
}

void Shader::SetVec3(const std::string& name, const glm::vec3& vec) const {
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(id_, name.c_str()), vec.x, vec.y, vec.z);
}

void Shader::SetMat4(const std::string& name, const glm::mat4& mat) const {
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(id_, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
}
```

Comment: Which line in the BuildTextureArray method causes the segfault? Please also add the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your texture is simply not found, or the 2 images don't have the same size. you don't actually check the return value of the image loader before using it in glTexSubImage, nor do you verify the images have the same size.

Testing return values should always be done, especially with file IO, since that always will fail at some point... Likewise for assumptions on image sizes... width/height of the new image should be checked - that it's the same size as the first image.

> And since I don't have debugger at hand, I cannot walk through that function.

Consider fixing that. You can't expect to be efficient with writing code without some way to look at what your code does in practice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem segfault occured in the second call to `stbi_load()` (inside for loop), where I have used `nullptr` for width, height and channels pointers. I don't know why, but width and hight pointers have to be specified. I put dummy stack ints for that and it worked.

```
uint32_t BuildTextureArray(const std::vector<std::string>& paths) {
    int width, height;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
    uint8_t *data_of_first = stbi_load(paths[0].c_str(), &width, &height, nullptr, 4);
    std::cout << "path: " << paths[0] << std::endl;
    if(data_of_first == nullptr){
        std::cerr << "cannot open '" << paths[0] << "'\n";
    }

    uint32_t array_id;
    glGenTextures(1, &array_id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, array_id);
    glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, paths.size(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    int a, b;
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data_of_first);
    for (int i = 1; i < paths.size(); i++) {
        uint8_t *data = stbi_load(paths[i].c_str(), &a, &b, nullptr, 4);
        if(data == nullptr){
            std::cerr << "cannot open '" << paths[i] << "'\n";
        }
        glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, i, width, height, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    }

    return array_id;
}
```

But since `stbi_load()` comes from third party and I don't control the implementation, there is nothing I can do about it. This is just for future readers if they cross upon this question